# How to use foreach in streams for my custom object?

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I need to iterate over Objects and add every elements name to ArrayList.
My class Command contains getName() method.

- commands = List< Command >

I've done it without streams.

```
     ArrayList<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>(); for
     (Command currentCommand : commands.getCommands()) {
     commandList.add(currentCommand.getName()); }
```

Here's what I've got now:

```
commands.getCommands().forEach(command -> { command.getName(); });
```

I want to do it in one line using streams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
commands.getCommands().stream().map(Command::getName).collect(toList());
```

Comment: It should be 
commands.getCommands().stream().map(Command::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
but it does not save it to commandList array in one line

Comment: Don’t forget the assignment, `List<String> commandList = …`